# Tiano Core UEFI - Pi 3B+ gone bad?

Tags: boot, pi-3b+, rip

I came across [this project on github](https://github.com/andreiw/RaspberryPiPkg) and I decided to give it a try. I copied the files over to my Raspberry Pi 3B+, put the sd card in, powered it up and the rainbow logo appeared, followed by a black screen, and I lost HDMI signal. I thought it was an issue with the project. I thought it didn't support 3B+ yet. I was wrong, because the Readme.md shows examples from a Raspberry Pi 3B+. I formatted my sd card, copied PINN and tried booting with the new contents, but I can no longer get any signal from the HDMI port and the ACT LED doesn't blink at all. The PWR LED is on, and the processor slowly gets warmer. What should I do now? I didn't do anything with GPIO pins.

EDIT: I use a mac, and I have been using a mac for all my Raspberry Pi SD cards. I don't think it's an issue with that, but can it effect the SD card?

EDIT 2: Issue is definitely not with my mac. I just tried the same thing with my Pi 3 and it works just fine (at least for now).

Comment: there is a [issue](https://github.com/andreiw/RaspberryPiPkg/issues/14) on the github project you might want to take a look at.

Comment: According to that issue, the pi still works with other OSes after trying to boot it up with UEFI.

Comment: you possibly damaged the pi physically - inspect the board and connectors (particularly the sd card slot) - I believe the 3B+ can boot from USB "out of the box" - so try that

Comment: also, make sure you are using an image that is definitely compatible with the 3B+

Comment: @JaromandaX Where did you get that information from?

Comment: which information? that the 3B+ can boot from USB out of the box? Not sure, read it somewhere (won't kill it to try)

Comment: I wish that’s the case. I’ll try to put NOOBS on a USB and try to boot from it.

Comment: I just tried it, and no, it doesn't boot from USB.